# sorting an array

Tags: c#, .net

Can anybody tell me how can i sort elements of an integer array in descending order? is it possible?

thank you

Comment: Why do you think it isn't possible ? Have you googled on the question regarding the ways of doing it?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried already? Did you search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx):

```
Array.Sort(myArray, (a, b) => b.Compare(a));
```

Answer (score 4):

To sort it in-place, you can use the overload that accepts a comparison delegate:

```
Array.Sort(arr, (x,y)=>y.Compare(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myIntArray = myIntArray.OrderBy(i => -1 * i).ToArray();
```

or

```
myIntArray = myIntArray.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToArray();
```

or

```
Array.Sort(myIntArray, (x,y) => x.Compare(y) * -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Sort()` followed by `Reverse()`

Comment: Though this works, there are sorting overloads that don't require reversing.

Comment: My intention with this answer was to provide the simplest (but not best) solution. The OP was asking such a basic question that I was afraid to throw lambdas into the mix.

Comment: Although I know that efficiency isn't really a concern in this particular instance, it's interesting to note that for primitive types, `Sort()` followed by `Reverse()` will execute almost three times as fast as calling `Sort` with a comparison delegate. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=781 for the reasons why.

Answer (score 1):

This may help if you have a class assignment and your professor doesn't want you to use `Array.Sort`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] numbers = { 7, 4, 2, 6, 1, 10, 5, 8, 9, 3 };
    SortArray(numbers);
    foreach (int n in numbers)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + n.ToString() + ' ';
    }
}

public static void SortArray(int[] num)
{
    int temp;
    int count = 0;

    while (count < num.Length - 1)
    {
        int min = num[count];

        for (int x = count; x < num.Length; x++)
        {
            if (min > num[x])
            {
                temp = num[count];
                min = num[x];
                num[count] = num[x];
                num[x] = temp;

            }

        }

        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.Sort(arr, (num1,num2) => num1.Compare(num2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => y.Compare(x));
```